# Execute commandButton inside form with validation errors

Tags: validation, jsf, facelets

I want to execute a function in the backingbean, using a CommandButton within a form with validation errors.

Using the code example, I want to call function 'resiCon.cancel()' regardless of whether validation errors on the form or not.

Can you help me?

```
<h:form id="mainform">

    ....      
    <h:inputText value="#{resiCon.code">
        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" />
    </h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton id="save" value="Save" update="mainform" action="#{resiCon.save()}"/>
    <h:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancel" update="mainform" action="#{resiCon.cancel()}"/>

</h:form>
```

Thank You, very much.

Tomcat v7.0, Myfaces 2.1.5, Spring 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways:

1. Add `immediate="true"` to the cancel button. This skips all input fields which do not have this set.

   ```
   <h:commandButton id="cancel" ... immediate="true" />
   ```

   This may only not work when you're already using `immediate="true"` in some input fields to prioritize validation.
2. Let it perform an ajax request wherein you only execute `@this` and thus ignore all fields.

   ```
   <h:commandButton id="cancel" ... >
       <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
   </h:commandButton>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `immediate="true"` on your `<h:commandButton>`. Here's an article specifically addressing Cancel buttons and the `immediate="true"` attribute: http://jerryorr.blogspot.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html